# Bootstrap Datetimepicker UK date format posts as US format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4, .net-5

I am using the [Bootstrap DateTime picker](https://getdatepicker.com/4/) and formatting it to a UK format in a .NET 5 MVC project using a Razor page front end.

The input is as below

```
<input type="text" asp-for="WeddingDate" class="form-control" onblur="WizardSummary('WeddingDate','SummaryWeddingDate')" required />
```

And the javascript initialing it

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        icons: {
            time: "fas fa-clock",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
            down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear: 'fa fa-trash',
            close: 'fa fa-remove'
        },
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    });
```

Fairly simple stuff. It all works absolute fine in the front end, it fires, formats the date etc... no issues at all.

However, when I POST the data to the controller for a date with a day > 12 (example todays date - 24/09/2021), it comes through as `0001/01/01 00:00:00` and I think this is because the model expects a standard DateTime, which would be US format and it translates it to this value. I can see in the chrome developer tools it is posting a value in UK format as expected.

[image: Data]

Extract of model below

```
public class WeddingWizardViewModel
    {
        public DateTime WeddingDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

What have I gotten wrong? How can I get my backend to recognise I am posting a valid format?

**Update** Here is the WizardSummary function, which is purely to copy the content of the input box into a text label that I display on a sumarry screen.

```
function WizardSummary(input, output) {
    var inputvalue = document.getElementById(input).value;
    document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = inputvalue;
}
```

**Controller method on submission of form***

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Wizard(WeddingWizardViewModel vm)
        {
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
            
            vm.TopBar = new TopBarViewModel();
            vm.TopBar.PageTitle = "Wedding Wizard";

            vm.TopBar.Breadcrumbs = new List<Breadcrumb>();

            var level1 = new Breadcrumb
            {
                Level = 1,
                Name = "Weddings",
                Controller = "Weddings",
                Action = "Index"
            };
            vm.TopBar.Breadcrumbs.Add(level1);

            var level2 = new Breadcrumb
            {
                Level = 2,
                Name = "Wizard",
                Controller = "Weddings",
                Action = "Wizard"
            };
            vm.TopBar.Breadcrumbs.Add(level2);

            this.ViewData["TopBarViewModel"] = vm.TopBar;

            var templatesegments = _context.TemplateSegments.Include(i => i.Shots.OrderBy(i => i.Id)).Where(i => i.TemplateId == vm.TemplateId).ToList() ;

            List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();

            foreach(var templatesegment in templatesegments)
            {
                Segment newseg = new Segment();
                newseg.CompanyId = user.CompanyId;
                newseg.Name = templatesegment.Name;
                newseg.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                newseg.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                newseg.StartTime = new DateTime(vm.WeddingDate.Year, vm.WeddingDate.Month, vm.WeddingDate.Day, vm.WeddingDate.Hour, vm.WeddingDate.Minute, vm.WeddingDate.Second);
                newseg.ReminderInMinutes = 15;
                newseg.ClientVisible = templatesegment.ClientVisible;
                newseg.Shots = new List<Shot>();

                foreach (var templateshot in templatesegment.Shots)
                {
                    
                    Shot newshot = new Shot();
                    newshot.CompanyId = user.CompanyId;
                    newshot.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    newshot.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    newshot.Name = templateshot.Name;
                    newshot.ClientVisible = templateshot.ClientVisible;
                    newshot.Sequence = templateshot.Sequence;
                    newseg.Shots.Add(newshot);
                }
                
                segments.Add(newseg);
            }

            Wedding wedding = new Wedding();
            wedding.Client1EMail = vm.Client1EMail;
            wedding.Client1FirstName = vm.Client1FirstName;
            wedding.Client1LastName = vm.Client1LastName;
            wedding.Client1FullMobileNumber = vm.Client1FullMobileNumber;
            wedding.Client1Role = vm.Client1Role;
            wedding.Client2EMail = vm.Client2EMail;
            wedding.Client2FirstName = vm.Client2FirstName;
            wedding.Client2FullMobileNumber = vm.Client2FullMobileNumber;
            wedding.Client2LastName = vm.Client2LastName;
            wedding.Client2Role = vm.Client2Role;
            wedding.CompanyId = user.CompanyId;
            wedding.Description = vm.Description;
            wedding.Name = vm.Name;
            wedding.Segments = segments;
            wedding.WeddingDate = vm.WeddingDate;





            _context.Add(wedding);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            //Image Upload 
            if (vm.WeddingAvatar != null)
            {
                var upload = await FileUpload.Upload(vm.WeddingAvatar, _env, user, "weddingavatars", wedding.Id.ToString());
                if (upload.Success == true)
                {
                    wedding.WeddingAvatarFileName = upload.FileName;
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Error uploading file");
                }
            }

            _context.Update(wedding);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            TempData["message"] = "Your wedding has been created and you can now start adding segments and shots to it";

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = wedding.Id });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to set the `locale` property of your date time picker; in the code bellow sounds an example of `UK locale`:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        icons: {
            time: "fas fa-clock",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
            down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear: 'fa fa-trash',
            close: 'fa fa-remove',
            locale: 'uk'
        },
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    });
```

And in Back-End, at Controller ActionResult method, add in first line this code bellow:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-uk");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: No, that has not helped. The problem is that it seems to be switched out at Model level. So in my ActionResult `public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(WeddingViewModel vm)` the property  `vm.WeddingDate` is already altered to 1/1/0001 so the culture info in the action isn;t making a difference

Comment: If your date is set to 1/1/0001, this means the that Date is not setted, because this value is a default value of DateTime type (like `default(DateTime)`). If possible, share more code details, because, for some reason, the Date is not setted.

Comment: Any idea exactly what code I should update with? I'm not sure its worth posting any of the HTML, as the posted value is displayed in the screenshot (WeddingDate property) so I can see the data is leaving the client side headed for the server side. The model that the controller is expecting is included also. I also know that the mapping must work, as if I set the date to 01/30/2021, the controller shows me it correctly, but setting the date to 30/01/2021 results in 01/01/0001. So which code would be helpful to share?

Comment: Please, share details of the ActionResult Controller and the Client Side function named `WizardSummary` (with `onblur` event), I'll try reproduce same scenario here

Comment: I have added the code, many thanks